# How to predict new data with offset in zero inflated negative binomial model

Tags: r, regression, offset

I am working with weighted survey data which is both over dispersed and zero inflated. My response variable is the number of trips an individual makes in a week. Individuals have different weights depending on the method of transport. See data below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  trips = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  weights = c(1.02, 1.11, 1.00, 1.35, 1.22, 1.15, 1.07, 1.00, 1.25, 1.60),
  gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"),
  age = c("0-15", "16+", "0-15", "16+", "0-15", "16+","0-15", "16+", "0-15", "16+"))

df <- mutate(df, weighted_trips = trips*weights)

trips weights gender  age       weighted_trips
1      1    1.02      M 0-15           1.02
2      2    1.11      M  16+           2.22
3      3    1.00      M 0-15           3.00
4      4    1.35      M  16+           5.40
5      5    1.22      M 0-15           6.10
6      6    1.15      F  16+           6.90
7      7    1.07      F 0-15           7.49
8      8    1.00      F  16+           8.00
9      9    1.25      F 0-15          11.25
10    10    1.60      F  16+          16.00
```

My covariates are all categorical variables.

My question is - how can I use the `zeroinfl()` function from the `pscl` package or any other function to model my data with a ZINB model?  I would like to take the weighting into consideration but count models should have a non-negative integer as the response.

After some research - it seems an offset here is what I should be going for. i.e.

```
zeroinfl(trips ~ gender + age + offset(log(weighted_trips)), data = df, dist = "negbin")
```

But how can I now use the `predict` function to predict new values if I do not have weights for the new data?

Comment: no.. it's not the offset. the offset is added as a term into the regression. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression

Comment: offset is used when your response is rate based, for example rate of bus arrivals, you have counts of bus arrivals, and the denominator is like a time period, which you use as offset.

Comment: in pscl zeroinfl, you can give weights, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pscl/versions/1.5.5/topics/zeroinfl, just provide it as weights = ...

Comment: In my case 'weighted_trips' would be considered rate data which is why I thought an offset is necessary.